# Can an Author in WordPress be given the option to export their own posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, export, roles

WordPress allows, by default, a user with *Administrator* role to export content.

I would like *Authors* to have the ability to export their own content. Only their own content.

I can give *Authors* access to export easily enough, but I can't work out how to limit the export to just their own content.

`export.php` provides an input for them to manually select individual authors. Lines 166-171

```
    <label><?php _e( 'Authors:' ); ?></label> 
<?php
    $authors = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'post'" );
    wp_dropdown_users( array( 'include' => $authors, 'name' => 'post_author', 'multi' => true, 'show_option_all' => __('All') ) );
?>
</li>
```

I'd like to take that away from them and simply force it to provide only the content that they have authored.

Can anyone suggest how I should rewrite these lines to force the export to only select the current users' own authored content?

A refinement of this would be if the user is an *Administrator* they should be able to select as usual, if they are an author they should only be given their own content.

I've tried to find a plugin for this, I believe there isn't one. It might make a good plugin project for someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach might be to use the user's author feed. For example, something.com/author/[username]/feed/ will give you an RSS feed of that user's content. You should then be able to import that to something else, easily enough.

A plugin would also work, but I'd urge you never to write any portion of WordPress. Pretty much every aspect of it can be overridden via plugins (or themes, as they both have pretty much the same effect).